# Custom Navigation drawer without ListView and ActionBar

Tags: android, listview, navigation, navigation-drawer

I use a navigation drawer in my app, which should look like [this]: http://godpowerturbo.com/app/uploads/nav.png [a], now to make it look like the design i have used `ImageButton` in place of a `ListView` plus i'm not using Fragments and i open the navigation drawer on a `ImageButton` click but it exits with a Null Pointer Exception.

I have searched everywhere on Google and StackOverflow but i couldn't fix the error.

This is the main Activity

```
   DrawerLayout dw;
   PercentRelativeLayout rl;
   ImageButton nav;    
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
        Session session = new Session(mCtx);
        Log.e(TAG, "LOG_ID: " + session.getLogId());
        session.putAll();
        rl = (PercentRelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_left);
        dw = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer);
        nav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nav_menu);
        nav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { //Opening the drawer returns a Null Pointer Exception
                Log.e(TAG, "Nav Menu Click!");
                dw.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });
    }
```

Navigation Drawer Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:background="@drawable/nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/nav_left"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="65dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp" />

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nav_home"
            android:id="@+id/lay_min"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/nav_catalogue"
                android:layout_width="205dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_below="@+id/nav_catalogue"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/nav_upcomingevents"
                android:layout_width="205dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_below="@+id/nav_upcomingevents"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/nav_newlaunch"
                android:layout_width="205dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_below="@+id/nav_newlaunch"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/nav_turbofailure"
                android:layout_width="205dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_below="@+id/nav_turbofailure"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/nav_aboutus"
                android:layout_width="205dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_below="@+id/nav_aboutus"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/nav_enquiry"
                android:layout_width="205dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_below="@+id/nav_enquiry"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/nav_faq"
                android:layout_width="205dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_below="@+id/nav_faq"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/nav_feedback"
                android:layout_width="205dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/lazy_view"
            android:layout_below="@id/lay_min"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_below="@+id/lazy_view"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/nav_back"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_below="@+id/nav_back"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/nav_exit"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Stack Trace

```
01-07 20:30:16.708  22258-22258/com.godpowerturbo.android E/Main﹕ Nav Menu Click!
01-07 20:30:16.708  22258-22258/com.godpowerturbo.android W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412c0438)
01-07 20:30:16.738  22258-22258/com.godpowerturbo.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.godpowerturbo.android.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:49)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16987)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4807)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now my problem is when i click the `ImageButton` crashes the app it raises a `Null Pointer Exception` when it reaches `dw.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);` the Log before it works.

And how do i access the image button in the Navigation drawer to launch different existing Activities.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `dw` is null because you never initialize it. But it also looks like `nav` should be null, too, in `onStart()`. Is that the exact code you're running?

Comment: could u elaborate @MikeM.

Comment: Post your stack trace, please.

Comment: plz check the code again

Comment: stack trace posted @MikeM.

Comment: There isn't a "caused by" line in the trace?

Comment: I really don't think that's the exact code you're running, but `dw` is null in `onStart()` because you've declared a `DrawerLayout dw;` in the `onCreate()` method's scope, and that's what gets initialized with the `findViewById()` call. Remove that declaration from `onCreate()`.

Comment: This is all i get there is no caused by line in this stack trace @Jey10

Comment: @MikeM. Actually i have declared it as global in the class

Comment: Yes, but you've declared another `dw` in `onCreate()`. They're not the same variable. Remove the declaration in `onCreate()`.

Comment: check it now @MikeM.

Comment: Nobody can help you unless you post your code _exactly_ as it is. Moving declarations around like that makes a huge difference. We need to know your exact code. We also need the complete stack trace.

Comment: I have posted the entire stack trace of the error this is what i get

Comment: This is how the declarations are right now i shortened the code to highlight the exact thing

Comment: But clicking the button may launch a lot of elements, so it would be useful to have the entire code, then we can highlight ourselves the things. Moreover the traces are very tiny so it's hard with this code